Ceph S3 and Signature Version 4 (SigV4) Support with Mountpoint for S3
I am currently working with a Ceph S3 Storage and using the S3-compatible API to interact with an object storage bucket. I attempted to mount the bucket using Mountpoint for S3 and I followed the same steps as mentioned here (https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3). This was the command that I used mount-s3 DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET /path/to/mount but encountered the following error:
Error: Failed to create S3 client
Caused by:
  0: initial ListObjectsV2 failed for bucket <bucket-name> in region <region>
  1: Client error
  2: Forbidden: The AWS Access Key ID you provided does not exist in our records.

I found this https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/10333 and it seems they support SigV4. I am seeking help on this issue. Specifically:
Does Ceph's S3 support AWS Signature Version 4 (SigV4) for authentication?
If Ceph supports SigV4, Do I need any specific configurations or workarounds to mount a ceph bucket using mountpoint s3?
It would be great if you can shed some light on this.
Thank you
